# How can I turn my program into a .dll file and run it in cmd using rundll32.exe?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I have a program that creates multiple threads and prints some strings in a loop. My task is to turn this program into a .dll and run it using rundll32.exe, but I've got no idea how can I run a .dll as an executable file.

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

typedef struct {
    std::string info;
    unsigned int m_number;
    int m_stop_thread;
    int m_priority_thread;
    unsigned m_cycles;
    unsigned m_currentThread;
}data;
HANDLE tmp;
unsigned int __stdcall Func(void* d) {
    data* real = (data*)d;
    std::cout << "\nCurrent thread ID: " << GetCurrentThreadId() << std::endl;
    if (real->m_currentThread == real->m_priority_thread)
        SetThreadPriority(tmp, 2);
        std::cout << "Thread priority: " << GetThreadPriority(tmp) << std::endl;
    for (int j = (real->m_currentThread - 1) * real->m_cycles / real->m_number;j < real->m_currentThread * real->m_cycles / real->m_number;j++) {
        for (int i = 0;i < real->info.size();++i)
            std::cout << real->info[i];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int threadsNumber, priority, stop;
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "Enter the info about a student:\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    std::cout << "Enter the number of threads:\n";
    std::cin >> threadsNumber;
    int cycles;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of cycles:\n";
    std::cin >> cycles;
    std::cout << "Which thread priority do you want to change? ";
    std::cin >> priority;
    std::cout << "Which thread do you want to stop? ";
    std::cin >> stop;
    std::vector<HANDLE> threads;

    data* args = new data;
    args->info = str;
    args->m_number = threadsNumber;
    args->m_cycles = cycles;
    args->m_priority_thread = priority;
    args->m_stop_thread = stop;
    clock_t time = clock();
    for (int i = 1;i <= threadsNumber;++i) {
        args->m_currentThread = i;
        tmp = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &Func, args, 0, 0);

        threads.push_back(tmp);
    }
    WaitForMultipleObjects(threads.size(), &threads.front(), TRUE, INFINITE);
    time = clock() - time;
    std::cout << "time: " << (double)time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "s" << std::endl << std::endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know how can I put this code into a dll and run it using command line?

Comment: Have a read of https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643   Then read the very old https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/164787/info-windows-rundll-and-rundll32-interface   Specifically note: _"...Rundll32 is a leftover from Windows 95, and it has been deprecated since at least Windows Vista..."_

Comment: Why don't you make a regular executable image, and run that from the command line? Why do you need the rundll32.exe interloper?

Comment: @IInspectable It's a part of the task I was given in college, so I need to do it exactly this way.

Comment: What particular issue is this requirement supposed to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable Well, I think this requirement is given to students in order to make them learn different ways of working with .dll files. Other tasks are more practical, e.g.,create a dll and then link it to another executable file.

Comment: possible better use `regsvr32.exe /u <your dll path> [possible some args]` and in this case you need export `HRESULT WINAPI DllRegisterServer()` as entry point. in this case not created not need to you window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile your program you make something called [Portable Executable [PE]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) in Windows. Among files that share that family are `.exe`,`.dll`, `.scr` and you can recognize them by opening them in text editor (such as notepad) and looking if file starts with [`MZ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable) which are signature for Mark Zbikowski.

In short there isn't much difference in `*.dll` or `*.exe` except some minor blocks depedning on version. So in short you are making an "dll" when you compile it. But if you wish to compile your program as `dll` exactly, that depends on your compiler:

1. If you are working in **Visual Studio**, Microsoft has some [tutorials for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019)
2. For **MinGW** you have [in code tutorial](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL)
3. And for **CygWin** you have [command line arguments for compiler](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html)
4. And for **Clang** I would suggest this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982440/build-shared-library-with-clang)

But I would be careful with deployment of such file, since @Richard nicely pointed it out that *RunDll32* is deprecated, but it is still used in gears of some programming language libraries. So if you are building something for self testing purposes I would recommend those 4 options depending on your compiler.